# Exporting source images for JAR

Tags: java, eclipse, image, executable-jar

I have a Java GUI game of an imitation of flappy bird that I am trying to export to other computers. I am confused as to what to set the relative/absolute path to in my code; or what methods to use to package everything in a JAR file to deploy.

I have created a new Source Folder in the same project that contains all the images for my code. I tried pointing the 'ImageIO.read' or the 'getClass().getResource()' to the source folder. I also tried creating path variables under linked resources to point to to the location of the images
I can only get my game to run if I point to the absolute path of the images, which is not good.

How do I point to the correct resource folder to access my images, for my program to run on multiple computers?

These are the errors I get when I try changing the path to a relative path:
-Can't read input
-null or nullpointerexception

Here is my code,
The commented sections is what I've tried from multiple google searches and multiple SO answers.
The non-commented section is the only code that runs, which is what I don't want.

[image]

Thanks for any advice ahead of time~

Comment: For example `ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/Resources/Bird.png");` or `ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/Bird.png");`.  You could unzip the jar file and see where eclipse has placed them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems/questions,  which have to be solved in the following order:
1) change your folder structure. 
2) package the jar file
3) access the images.
(3) won't work before (2), and (2) not (reasonable) before (1).

1) for your purposes, stop treating java source files and image files so different. Put them in one package ( folder) in eclipse, or in a subpaclage.
2) right click on the project and choose export. Choose jar and select name and all files.
3) the path of the images is packagename+filename, with dots replaced by slashes (e.g. com/flappy/game/images/bird.gif). Use imageio read command from mad programmer to get images.